# ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, написал простой GET запрос. Приложение запускается, но падает когда пытаюсь выполнить функцию кнопке. Не могу понять, что делаю не так.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void getCurrencyClick(View v) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CurencyTextView);

        try {
 /*
  определяем URL сервиса
  готовим API, позволяющий выполнять разбор документа
  загружаем в парсер полученный ответ и вызываем метод parse
  */
            URL url = new URL("https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?exchange&coursid=3");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
 /*получаем агрегатный узел с дочерними узлами с атрибутами, хранящими значения валют;
 в ответе всего два узла, мы возьмем первый, а при необходимости тут вполне можно запустить цикл с nodeList.getLength
*/

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("exchangerate");
            Node node = nodeList.item(0);
            // опускаемся на узел ниже и получаем список его атрибутов
            NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getFirstChild().getAttributes();
            //получаем значение атрибут buy
            Node currencyAttribEUR = attributes.getNamedItem("buy");
            // ... и его значение
            String currencyValueEUR = currencyAttribEUR.getNodeValue();

            // и выводим информацию
            tv.setText(currencyValueEUR);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            tv.setText("Не удалось выполнить операцию");
        }


    }
}
```

Лог ошибки

```
com.harbinger.simple_http_request, PID: 23475
                                                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5624)
                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22441)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6317)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5624) 
                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22441) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6317) 
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872) 
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762) 
                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
                                                                                           at com.harbinger.simple_http_request.MainActivity.getCurrencyClick(MainActivity.java:30)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5624) 
                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22441) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6317) 
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

И Activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/CurencyTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context="com.harbinger.simple_http_request.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:text="Курс покупки"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.487"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.027"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/getCurrencyClick"
        android:layout_width="377dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:onClick="getCurrencyClick"
        android:text="Узнать курс"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="14dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="111dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: не может скастовать `ConstraintLayout`  к `TextView`, что не удивительно. вы назначили id контейнеру, а пытаетесь сделать из него виджет `TextView`, видимо ошиблись и нужно перенести `android:id="@+id/CurencyTextView"` из атрибутов `ConstrainLayout` в атрибуты `TextView`. Об этом прямо сказано в ошибке, на правильном английском, если ее прочитать.

Comment: Так же, поскольку работа метода `findViewById()` весьма ресурсозатратна, рекомендуется получать ссылки на виджеты один раз, в методе `onCreate()` и затем хранить их в поле класса, а не каждый раз получать одно и то же значение при каждом клике на кнопку.

Comment: Далее, кнопка у вас "подвешена в воздухе", ей не назначены никакие привязки (констрайнты) ни к другим виджетам ни к  родительскому контейнеру, IDE должна была предупредить об этом, а при тестах вы должны были заметить, что расположение кнопки на экране произвольное. Для такой простой разметки вообще разумнее использовать более легкий контейнер, как `LinearLayout`, например.

Comment: И ещё, все сетевые операции должны выполняться в отдельном потоке, а не в UI потоке как у вас.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое! Действительно помогло!

> не может скастовать ConstraintLayout к TextView, что не удивительно.
>   вы назначили id контейнеру, а пытаетесь сделать из него виджет
>   TextView, видимо ошиблись и нужно перенести
>   android:id="@+id/CurencyTextView" из атрибутов ConstrainLayout в
>   атрибуты TextView. Об этом прямо сказано в ошибке, на правильном
>   английском, если ее прочитать. – pavlofff